# Upgrade pip error while installing Django

Tags: python, django, pip

I tried to install Django using `pip install Django`, later I got an error which says `upgrade pip`. I also tried to upgrade pip, but still getting error as follows,

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpQ3q.png)

Stack trace of error:

```
WARNING: The script sqlformat.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Easwar Sai 
Prasad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress 
this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
WARNING: The script django-admin.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\Easwar 
Sai Prasad\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on 
PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress 
this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Comment: `Error` != `Warning` And just follow the instructions it gives.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand is you are using a Windows machine and are trying to install django, and it's dependencies in an environment.

You can do that but a much better way is to use Virtual Environments. With virtual environments you don't need to set any variables, you just have to activate your VEnv and install dependencies like normal `pip3 install django`

Follow this guide https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html